# Enhanced Video Renderer renders 8 bit YUY2 but not 10 bit Y210

Tags: c++, bit-shift, ms-media-foundation, yuv

I have written a standalone implementation of the [Media Foundation Enhanced Video Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/enhanced-video-renderer) based on [Aaron Clauson's samples](https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/tree/master/MFBitmapToEVR). I am feeding it `Y210` 10 bit YUV 4:2:2 video (extracted from a SMPTE 2110-20 RTP stream) but it only renders a black screen with no errors - either from the `HRESULTS` or whilst using `MFTRACE`.

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/10-bit-and-16-bit-yuv-video-formats#422-formats), I have placed the 10 bit values into a 16 bit WORD with the lower 6 bits set to 0 as padding.

[image]

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < intermediateByteBuffer.size(); i += 5) //intermediateBYTEBuffer is a vector of uint8_t that holds 5 byte "pGroups". Each 10 bits is moved into a new WORD array element and padded
{
    //WORD buffer order is 1,0,3,2 to convert samples from Cb, Y0, Cr, Y1 to Y0, Cb, Y1, Cr as specified in Y210 and YUY2
    intermediateWORDBuffer[1 + x] = (((uint16_t)intermediateByteBuffer[0 + i] & 0b11111111u) << (0 + 8)) | (((uint16_t)intermediateByteBuffer[1 + i] & 0b11000000u) << 0);
    intermediateWORDBuffer[0 + x] = (((uint16_t)intermediateByteBuffer[1 + i] & 0b00111111u) << (2 + 8)) | (((uint16_t)intermediateByteBuffer[2 + i] & 0b11110000u) << 2);
    intermediateWORDBuffer[3 + x] = (((uint16_t)intermediateByteBuffer[2 + i] & 0b00001111u) << (4 + 8)) | (((uint16_t)intermediateByteBuffer[3 + i] & 0b11111100u) << 4);
    intermediateWORDBuffer[2 + x] = (((uint16_t)intermediateByteBuffer[3 + i] & 0b00000011u) << (6 + 8)) | (((uint16_t)intermediateByteBuffer[4 + i] & 0b11111111u) << 6);
    x += 4;
}
```

I can convert the 10 bit data to 8 bit `YUY2` by right-shifting each WORD by 8 (`>> 6` to account for padding and `>> 2` for the logical conversion from 10 to 8 bit) and the renderer will display the video frame with no problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < intermediateWORDBuffer.size(); i += 8)
{
    renderBuffer[i + 0] = (intermediateWORDBuffer[i + 0] >> 8); //renderBuffer is a uint8_t vector
    renderBuffer[i + 1] = (intermediateWORDBuffer[i + 1] >> 8);
    renderBuffer[i + 2] = (intermediateWORDBuffer[i + 2] >> 8);
    renderBuffer[i + 3] = (intermediateWORDBuffer[i + 3] >> 8);
    renderBuffer[i + 4] = (intermediateWORDBuffer[i + 4] >> 8);
    renderBuffer[i + 5] = (intermediateWORDBuffer[i + 5] >> 8);
    renderBuffer[i + 6] = (intermediateWORDBuffer[i + 6] >> 8);
    renderBuffer[i + 7] = (intermediateWORDBuffer[i + 7] >> 8);
}
```

This leads me to question why the renderer will accept 8 bit not 10 bit (16 including padding) as for the conversion to work it needs valid 10 bit data from the start. I have also tried swapping the order of the pixel samples, but this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer here for anyone who else who stumbles across this.

I never did find the answer, and after consulting the Microsoft Media Foundation forums, have concluded this a bug within Media Foundation.

See Microsoft's answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/325852/enhanced-video-renderer-renders-8-bit-yuy2-but-not.html)